# How can we style the text that appears as Activity label/title in android

Tags: android, label

When we define any activity in our manifest file there's a tag called android:label in which what we generally do is this android:label="@string/app_name"

So this string appears at the top of the screen and in case of honeycomb 3.0 it is always visible on the top in the Action Bar.
Now by default this text appears in white color, but my requirement is to add colors for certain parts of this text and to also make it appear in two lines.
eg.-  The application name is - "Poe's The Raven". I want Poe's in one line and the Raven in next plus the word Poe's should be in yellow color.
Hope I made it clear.
Please let me know how can we achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your target API? pre-honeycomb?

Answer (score 0):

please check this ...

[Custom title bar without padding (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665507/custom-title-bar-without-padding-android)

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/custom-android-window-title/

[Gradient styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450801/gradient-styles)